Why does my LiDAR have a blindspot?
I'm using the YDLIDAR X4 (which doesn't seem to have any part of its view blocked) for SLAM but I'm not getting any points from a specific angle, maybe about 45º wide and kind of towards the right-back from the LiDAR (the blindspot remains in the same direction from the LiDAR's perspective if I rotate it, so it's not about surface material or anything like that).
Why might this be happening?

The issue was solved by switching from the X4 config file to the X2 one with the X4 baud rate (128000). Not sure why this is the case, but the blindspot's gone.

Interesting since the params table suggest 115k for the X2.
For my X4 I had to discover I have to set frequency to 9 while the table suggests 5-12.
Python straight:

laser.setlidaropt(ydlidar.LidarPropSerialPort, port);
laser.setlidaropt(ydlidar.LidarPropSerialBaudrate, 128000);
laser.setlidaropt(ydlidar.LidarPropLidarType, ydlidar.TYPE_TRIANGLE);
laser.setlidaropt(ydlidar.LidarPropDeviceType, ydlidar.YDLIDAR_TYPE_SERIAL);
laser.setlidaropt(ydlidar.LidarPropScanFrequency, 9);
laser.setlidaropt(ydlidar.LidarPropSampleRate, 5);
laser.setlidaropt(ydlidar.LidarPropSingleChannel, True);


ros2 humble ydlidar.yaml:
pi@GoPi5Go:DOCKER:~/GoPi5Go/ros2ws/src/ydlidar_ros2_driver $ more params/ydlidar.yaml
ydlidar_ros2_driver_node:
  ros__parameters:
    port: /dev/ttyUSB0
    frame_id: base_scan
    ignore_array: ""
    baudrate: 128000
    lidar_type: 1
    device_type: 6
    sample_rate: 5
    abnormal_check_count: 4
    fixed_resolution: true
    reversion: false
    inverted: true
    auto_reconnect: true
    isSingleChannel: false
    intensity: false
    support_motor_dtr: true
    angle_max: 180.0
    angle_min: -180.0
    range_max: 10.0
    range_min: 0.12
    frequency: 9.0
    invalid_range_is_inf: false



Sorry I mixed them up I had the X4 and for some reason have to use the X2 file.
